# Getting Alias from items in Outlook AddressBook with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server, addressbook

My code below gives me the following error  at the Debug.Print(oExuser.Alias),  why?

[image]

Sub Test()

```
Dim AliasName, FullName As String
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.nameSpace
Dim myAddrList As AddressList
Dim myAddrEntries As AddressEntries
Dim myAddrEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry
Dim myAlias As Object
Dim oExUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser

Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myAddrList = myNameSpace.GetGlobalAddressList()


Set myAddrEntries = myAddrList.AddressEntries
Set myAddrEntry = myAddrEntries.Item(1)

Set oExUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

Debug.Print (oExUser.Alias)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to be connected to the *Exchange server* to use the [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser) method. The following code makes sense only for the Exchange accounts:

```
Set oExUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

Debug.Print (oExUser.Alias)
```

The `Alias` property returns an empty string if this property has not been implemented or does not exist for the `ExchangeUser` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the returned `ExchangeUser` object (`oExUser`) is not null. It will be null for the non-Exchange (e.g., SMTP) address entries even if you have Exchange in the current Outlook profile:

```
If not (oExUser Is Nothing) Then
    Debug.Print (oExUser.Alias)
End If
```